# How to search specific attribute within a tag and remove it using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I have this kind of tag (just for example)

```
<div type="text" onclick="event();" onblur="event();">this div has onclick and onblur functions</div>
```

and I want to remove some attributes to that tag using a reference variable.

```
var refAttribs = ['onclick', 'onblur'];
```

So it should strip out all attributes from `refAttribs`.
Be **careful** not to strip out the content of the div. Because it also contains a string from the `refAttribs` variable.

How do I get rid of them using a regex?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  In what way did it not work?  Why do you need a regex?  Are you allowed to use other techniques, or is this a homework question?

Comment: I can't see *how* to use regex in this case since you don't handle the entire code as text, but as a dom tree.

Comment: I edit my question. The tag is a string. SO I want to use regex to stripout attributes from the reference variable. I'm no good on regex so I did try to ask a question here. Any techniques are allowed of course. Thanks

Comment: If you're worried about script injection, just stripping out `on*` attributes isn't good enough. You also need to watch out for stuff like `<iframe src="javascript:alert('hi')"></iframe>`, among other things.

Comment: Using regex to look into HTML is not a good idea, as always..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try this:

To remove onclick, the regex will be:

```
    (<[^>]+)\s+onclick\s*=[\'"].*?[\'"]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RFK0SbImlJdgrdaC)

The removeAttr function:

```
function removeAttr(html, attr) {

    return html.replace(new RegExp('(<[^>]+)\\s+' + attr + '\\s*=[\'"].*?[\'"]', 'gi'), '$1');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/pC4aH/1/

Comment: Wow thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Only between < > and looking globaly, thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

As you've stated the tag is a string then you could santise it with the following javascript.

```
var refAttribs = ['onclick', 'onblur'];
function remove(tagToClean)
{
    var result = tagToClean;

    for(var i=0; i<refAttribs.length; i++)
    {
        regex = new RegExp(refAttribs[i] + "=\"[a-zA-Z\(\);]*?\"", "g");
        result = result.replace(regex, "");
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can call the method by passing in your string.

```
remove('<div type="text" onclick="event();" onblur="event();">this div has onclick and onblur functions</div>');
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to modify the DOM? If so you will need to modify the method to accept a handle to a DOM node. A little more information would help.